# MySQL : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails when insert my data to database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I got an error like this : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails when insert my data to database phpmyadmin using Codeigniter.

**This is my error message :**

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tugasakhir`.`tb_pasien`, CONSTRAINT `tb_pasien_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`kode_pasien`) REFERENCES `tb_jk` (`kode_jk`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
>
> INSERT INTO `tb_pasien` (`nama_pasien`, `email_pasien`, `username`, `password`, `alamat_pasien`, `tanggal_lahir`, `umur`, `kode_jk`, `no_telp`, `no_antrian`) VALUES ('nandoku', 'gustiayuri@gmail.com', 'nandoku', '827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b', 'dalung', '11/12/1995', '21', 'L', '567890', 0)

**This is my controller :**

```
public function insert()
{      
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('p_model');

    $data_pasien = array(
        "nama_pasien" => $this->input->post('nama_pasien'),
        "email_pasien" => $this->input->post('email_pasien'),
        "username" => $this->input->post('username'),
        "password" => md5($this->input->post('password')),
        "alamat_pasien" => $this->input->post('alamat_pasien'),
        "tanggal_lahir" => $this->input->post('tanggal_lahir'),
        "umur" => $this->input->post('umur'),
        "kode_jk" => $this->input->post('kode_jk'),
        "no_telp" => $this->input->post('no_telp'),
        "no_antrian" => $this->input->post('no_antrian')
    );

    $data_jk = array(
      'nama_jk'       => $this->input->post('nama_jk')
    );    

    $this->p_model->insert_entry($data_pasien, $data_jk);
}
```

**Model :**

```
    function insert_entry($data_pasien, $data_jk) {

    $this->db->insert('tb_pasien', $data_pasien);

    $data_pasien['kode_jk'] = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->insert('nama_jk', $data_pasien);

}
```

**View**

```
 <!-- form start -->
        <form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/a_controller/tambahmanual' ?>" method="post">
          <div class="box-body">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputNama">Nama Pasien</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_pasien" id="exampleInputNama" placeholder="Nama Pasien">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail">Email Pasien</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email_pasien" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Email Pasien">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputUsername">Username</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="exampleInputUsername" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword">Password</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputAlamat">Alamat</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="alamat_pasien" id="exampleInputAlamat" placeholder="Alamat">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Tanggal lahir</label>

            <div class="input-group date">
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </div>
              <input type="date" name="tanggal_lahir" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <!-- /.input group -->
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputUmur">Umur</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="umur" id="exampleInputUmur" placeholder="Umur">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Jenis Kelamin</label>
              <select name="kode_jk" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">L</option>
                <option value="2">P</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputTelp">No. Telp</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="no_telp" id="exampleInputTelp" placeholder="No. Telp">
                </div>
            </div>


            

          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->

          <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

This is my tables :

```html
CREATE TABLE `tb_pasien` (
  `kode_pasien` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nama_pasien` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email_pasien` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `alamat_pasien` text NOT NULL,
  `tanggal_lahir` date NOT NULL,
  `umur` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `kode_jk` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `no_telp` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `no_antrian` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`kode_pasien`),
  CONSTRAINT `tb_pasien_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`kode_pasien`) REFERENCES `tb_jk` (`kode_jk`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `tb_jk` (
  `kode_jk` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nama_jk` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`kode_jk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

[image: value for my tb_jk] 
Note : *kode_jk is foreign key on tb_pasien table.*
What should i do for this error message?

Answer (score 1):

**Note :** The number of columns in the child table and parent table specified in the FOREIGN KEY and REFERENCES must be the same and also the data type.

**Table 'tb_pasien' :**

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_pasien` (
  `kode_pasien` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nama_pasien` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email_pasien` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `alamat_pasien` text NOT NULL,
  `tanggal_lahir` date NOT NULL,
  `umur` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `kode_jk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_telp` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `no_antrian` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`kode_pasien`),
  CONSTRAINT `tb_pasien_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`kode_jk`) REFERENCES `tb_jk` (`kode_jk`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `tb_jk` (
  `kode_jk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nama_jk` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`kode_jk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: thankyou. it's work but my problem now , I need to show L or P on my tb_pasien from kode_jk but it keep showing 1 or 2 instead L or P @pradeep.

Comment: change foreign key this way  : CONSTRAINT `tb_pasien_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY ('nama_jk') REFERENCES `tb_jk` ('nama_jk') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

Comment: uhm, sorry. when i try to change it using phpmyadmin, it wont allowed. i just realized that why it keep showing 1 or 2 t because of my option value on my View

Comment: don't forget to change the field name from kode_jk to nama_jk in tb_pasien and also data type of field as of the field nama_jk.

Comment: so, nama_jk will be the foreign key? but isnt it weird?

Comment: if you don't want to change the field name ,keep it as it was before simply change  REFERENCES

Answer (score 0):

kode_jk value must be available in your tb_jk table before inserting in tb_pasien.

Comment: i already insert value on my tb_jk. check my post, i edited it. @abhay

Comment: You have hard-coded it with 1 and 2. Which value you are selecting from kode_jk?

Comment: I need to show L or P on my tb_pasien from kode_jk.

Comment: You have passed Laki-laki value for kode_jk which is wrong, it must be of int type and you can only pass kode_jk  value which is already present in tb_jk table.

Comment: oopps, sorry my mistake. I change it already to L value. but now, it showing 1 not L. I want to show L or P only not 1 or 2

Comment: edit your code as currently you have and your passing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you insert into the main table before the sub table. 
You can also suppress foreign key check in your inserts.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding field name, which foreign key is set on, to an "allowed_fields" array in Model, fixed the issue.